# ArgumentNullException crashes my wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application(Dotnet V4.5) and it runs smoothly for like 3-4 hours and all of a sudden it crashes.
I have caught the exception which says "Value cannot be null;Parameter Name Key".
I have the stack trace that is as follows:

> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.FindEntry(TKey key)   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.TryGetValue(TKey key,
>   TValue& value)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridItemAttachedStorage.TryGetValue(Object
>   item, DependencyProperty property, Object& value)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.RestoreAttachedItemValue(DependencyObject
>   objectWithProperty, DependencyProperty property)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.SyncProperties(Boolean
>   forcePrepareCells)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.PrepareRow(Object item, DataGrid
>   owningDataGrid)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject
>   element, Object item)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.MS.Internal.Controls.IGeneratorHost.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject
>   container, Object item)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.InsertContainer(Int32
>   childIndex, UIElement container, Boolean isRecycled)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.AddContainerFromGenerator(Int32
>   childIndex, UIElement child, Boolean newlyRealized, Boolean
>   isBeforeViewport)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(IItemContainerGenerator&
>   generator, IContainItemStorage& itemStorageProvider,
>   IContainItemStorage& parentItemStorageProvider, Object& parentItem,
>   Boolean& hasUniformOrAverageContainerSizeBeenSet, Double&
>   computedUniformOrAverageContainerSize, Double&
>   computedUniformOrAverageContainerPixelSize, Boolean&
>   computedAreContainersUniformlySized, IList& items, Object& item,
>   IList& children, Int32& childIndex, Boolean& visualOrderChanged,
>   Boolean& isHorizontal, Size& childConstraint, Rect& viewport,
>   VirtualizationCacheLength& cacheSize, VirtualizationCacheLengthUnit&
>   cacheUnit, Boolean& foundFirstItemInViewport, Double&
>   firstItemInViewportOffset, Size& stackPixelSize, Size&
>   stackPixelSizeInViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheBeforeViewport,
>   Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Size& stackLogicalSize,
>   Size& stackLogicalSizeInViewport, Size&
>   stackLogicalSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size&
>   stackLogicalSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Boolean&
>   mustDisableVirtualization, Boolean isBeforeFirstItem, Boolean
>   isAfterFirstItem, Boolean isAfterLastItem, Boolean skipActualMeasure,
>   Boolean skipGeneration, Boolean&
>   hasBringIntoViewContainerBeenMeasured, Boolean&
>   hasVirtualizingChildren)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl(Size
>   constraint, Nullable'1& lastPageSafeOffset, List'1&
>   previouslyMeasuredOffsets, Nullable`1& lastPagePixelSize, Boolean
>   remeasure)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()    at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
>   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
>   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object
>   resizedCompositionTarget)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object
>   resizedCompositionTarget)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

A strange thing I found was the application doesnot crash on some machines but it crashes on some other machines.So I took a dump of both the files and noticed that  version of "PresentationCore.ni.dll" was 4.6.81.0 and CLR version of system was 4.6.100.0 this is with respect to a machine where my app didnot crash when it ran continuously for straight 7 hours.

In the machine(s) where it was crashing , the that  version of "PresentationCore.ni.dll" was 4.6.1055.0 and CLR version of system was 4.6.1055.0 .

Could someone help me with my situation? I feel like I am missing something over here not understanding what.

Comment: The `key` parameter is almost definitely `null`. Check your code and ensure that passing a `null` value to `FindEntry` is impossible.

Comment: It's impossible to help without any code. The call stack shows that the error was thrown by a DataGrid. Did you try to bind the grid to a null variable or something?

Comment: @MikeEason  I find it strange that same piece of code works well on another machine but fails in my and colleague's machine. Findentry is built in method I am pretty sure that I am not passing/binding any null value to any row

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using a user control and it is being used at two places in a same window, not able to find out where exactly the exception is being raised. The stacktrace I have posted is from Application Dispatcher unhandled exception.

Comment: Debugging dependency properties is excessively little fun.  This kind of randomness, and the nature of the crash, points at a threading bug.  Like updating bound data from a worker thread.  Fairly classic mistake.

Comment: @kedarK 2nd call from the top and lower are DataGridItemAttachedStorage, DataGridRow.RestoreAttachedItemValue etc.

Comment: Checking the source for [DataGridItemAttachedStorage.TryGetValue](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGridItemAttachedStorage.cs,24) it looks like either the bound object is null or the dependency property is null. Where does your DataGrid bind to? Is there any chance that you have a List<T> or array where one item is null? Do you change the bindings at runtime? Please post the code!

Comment: Hi All,
Thank you for your time and help, I am able to see in onitemssourcechanged event of my custom datagrid that one of the item is null not sure why, I am still debugging this issue. The scenario is that my datagrid keeps updating every few (3-4) seconds. I havent got any break in the code where the data is fetched from, wonder why its on the control side.